# I can not ping db deploying docker with azure

Tags: azure, docker, go

I followed these instructions https://medium.com/@durgaprasadbudhwani/step-by-step-guide-to-deploy-golang-application-on-azure-web-app-46ba3befb4c0 to deploy my app. The app connects to db running docker locally, but when I deploy to azure pinging the db times out.

Here are the logs:

```
2023-04-04T02:08:47.385Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container app_0_cfbd4891. Elapsed time = 45.6099877 sec
2023-04-04T02:09:01.757899494Z 2023/04/04 02:09:01 ping db timed out
```

There error message is coming from this section of my code

```
var PING_DB_ATTEMPTS = 60

func NewHandlerService(maria_repo maria_db.DbInterface, sugaredLogger *zap.SugaredLogger) (*HandlerService, error) {

    for i := 0; i < PING_DB_ATTEMPTS; i++ {
        if err := maria_repo.Ping(); err == nil {
            return &HandlerService{
                maria_repo:    maria_repo,
                sugaredLogger: sugaredLogger,
            }, nil
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

    return &HandlerService{}, errors.New("ping db timed out")
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: s-go
    ports:
      - 80:80
    # This is what makes the hot reloading work inside of a Docker container
    volumes:
      - .:/s/
    environment:
      - GIN_MODE=release 
    depends_on:
      - maria-db
          condition: service_healthy
  maria-db:
    image: mariadb:10-focal
    container_name: s-maria-db
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --password=secret --silent"]
      interval: 3s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    expose:
      - "3306:3306"
    # setting some env vars to create the DB
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "secret"   
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "s_db"

    # we mount a data volume to make sure we don't lose data
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db-data:
```

**updated deploying with multi container instructions**

Following Azure quickstart multicontainer instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container, but I see:

```
2023-04-06T23:37:07.751Z ERROR - Exception in multi-container config parsing: YamlException: (Line: 7, Col: 9, Idx: 73) - (Line: 7, Col: 9, Idx: 73): Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}.
2023-04-06T23:37:07.752Z ERROR - Start multi-container app failed
```

Comment: Include `err` into your error message: at the moment you're ignoring it.

Comment: @zerkms great point! Updated question with the answer.

Comment: Are you running a database also in Azure? It seems like you may have deployed your app container, but you have no DB deployed in Azure. The guide you posted doesn't include any details about databases...

Comment: @sytech thanks, that may actually be the issue. It was my understanding that my db would be deployed as multi container, however, I am starting to think that a db needs to be configured in Azure as well. I am new to deploying.